# How iterate over the an API response and search for a particular string?

Tags: java, rest, hl7-fhir

[image: API content]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tew1u.jpg

I am new to using API's. The only thing I can currently do is search for a diagnostic report via ID by using the code:

```java
DiagnosticReport dR = client.read().resource(DiagnosticReport.class).withId("3281").execute();
```

But how can I search to see if a subject with reference: "Patient/3250" exists, and if it exists, how can I return the string "Encounter/3267" from:

`"context": { "reference": "Encounter/3267"`

Comment: Use a JSON parser, like gson, jackson etc

Comment: what is `DiagnosticReport`?

Comment: This is about FHIR (http://hl7.org/fhir), presumably, from the code, using HAPI (http://hapifhir.io/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with JSON :-

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON);
JSONObject getFirst = jsonObject.getJSONObject("Context");
Object level2 = getFirst.get("reference");
if(level2.equals("Patient/3250")){
    System.out.println("True");
    }
else{
    System.out.println("False");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do the first part with a query. I'm not sure about the HAPI syntax for it, so I'll show it in a URL. Your query is

```
GET [base]/DiagnosticReport/3281
```

The query you want for searching to see if a subject with reference "Patient/3250" exists would be

```
GET [base]/DiagnosticReport?subject:Patient.id=3250
```